# Adding ffmpeg to heroku buildback nodejs

Tags: node.js, heroku, ffmpeg, child-process, buildpack

I've been trying to make a server that can visualize music ([This is what I have so far](https://html5music.herokuapp.com/)). That's been successful but I want to try and make it work with youtube videos, and I've found a lot of repositories on github for youtube video to audio conversion that make this reasonably doable, but in order to deploy a server on heroku that can host temporary audio files of youtube videos in the format that I want, I'd need to include [`ffmpeg`](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html) in a buildpack and I'm not sure how to go about doing that. This is the [heroku buildpack for node.js](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs) but I don't really understand how it works.

**TL;DR**: What steps would I need to follow after forking the heroku-buildpack-nodejs repository on github in order to successfully deploy a node.js server to heroku and run this code?

```
var conversionProcess = child_process.spawn(
  'ffmpeg',
  ['-i', 'some_youtube_audio.mp3', 'some_youtube_audio.webm'],
  {
    cwd: __dirname + '/tmp'
  }
);
```

The documentation for this function is on the [node.js API](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options), by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use the multipack https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi

then use the node buildpack as well as an ffmpeg buildpack https://github.com/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest

Comment: Thank you so much, that sounds a lot easier than I was expecting!